# Spring Boot authentication throws java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I can successfully signup users. However, when it comes to logging in the following error is thrown. I couldn't solve this problem for days.

**stacktrace**

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api/v1] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
...
```

Here is where the error is thrown

```
  public AuthenticationResponse loginUser(LoginRequest request) {
        AuthenticationResponse authenticationResponse = new AuthenticationResponse();
        AppUser appUser = appUserService.getAppUserByEmail(request.getEmail());

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getEmail(), request.getPassword());
        Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken); //Thin
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        String jwtToken = tokenManager.generateToken(auth);
        authenticationResponse.setAccessToken("Bearer " + jwtToken);
        authenticationResponse.setRefreshToken(refreshTokenService.createRefreshToken(appUser));
        authenticationResponse.setAppUser(AppUserResponse.convert(appUser));
        return authenticationResponse;
    }
```

**AppUser** entity

```
package com.napsam.wo.entities;


import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.*;

@Entity
public class AppUser implements UserDetails, Serializable {
    @Id
  /*  @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )*/
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long appUserId;


    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    @NotBlank(message = "Email boş olamaz")
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotBlank
    private String password;
    private String fullName;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;
    private String biography;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
    private String avatar;
    private int score;
    private boolean isEnabled;
    private boolean isLocked;
    public AppUser() {
    }

    public AppUser(Long appUserId,
                   String email,
                   String username,
                   String password,
                   String fullName,
                   Gender gender,
                   String biography,
                   LocalDateTime createdAt,
                   LocalDateTime updatedAt,
                   String avatar,
                   int score, boolean isLocked) {
        this.appUserId = appUserId;
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.biography = biography;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
        this.avatar = avatar;
        this.score = score;
        this.isLocked = isLocked;
    }

    public Long getAppUserId() {
        return appUserId;
    }

    public void setAppUserId(Long appUserId) {
        this.appUserId = appUserId;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getBiography() {
        return biography;
    }

    public void setBiography(String biography) {
        this.biography = biography;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(LocalDateTime updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return !isLocked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }


}
```

I tried to use `lombok` but didn't work. I tried to override `toString`, `hashCode` and `equals` methods but didn't work either.

If further information is required, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class that defines the method `loginUser(LoginRequest request)` is an implementation of the interface `AuthenticationProvider` then the part of your code which calls
`Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken)` might resolve in an infinite loop which will fill up your stack.

The default implementation of the `AuthenticationManager` is the `ProviderManager` class. `ProviderManager` loops through the implementations of `AuthenticationProvider` within the Spring Application and calls their `AuthenticationProvider#authenticate` method.

So if your method

```
  public AuthenticationResponse loginUser(LoginRequest request) {
    AuthenticationResponse authenticationResponse = new AuthenticationResponse();
    AppUser appUser = appUserService.getAppUserByEmail(request.getEmail());

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getEmail(), request.getPassword());
    Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken); //Thin
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
    String jwtToken = tokenManager.generateToken(auth);
    authenticationResponse.setAccessToken("Bearer " + jwtToken);
    authenticationResponse.setRefreshToken(refreshTokenService.createRefreshToken(appUser));
    authenticationResponse.setAppUser(AppUserResponse.convert(appUser));
    return authenticationResponse;
}
```

is inside a class which is an implementation of `AuthenticationProvider` you are infinitely looping between the `AuthenticationManager` and `AuthenticationProvider`

Example: `authenticationManager.authenticate()` calls `authenticationProvide.authenticate()` calls `authenticationManager.authenticate()` and you stack gets filled up.

p.s. You can also check out the spring documentation for `AuthenticationManager` [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#servlet-authentication-providermanager)